# Create JSON object from one to another with little tweak

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, object

How to convert the below 1st JSON object to the 2nd one in TypeScript/JavaScript? The second one does not have field "c" and "d" in field2. Thanks!

First Object:

```
 {
    "id" : 1,
    "field1": "property1" 
    "field2": [ 
                    {
                        "a": "A",
                        "b": "B",
                        "c": "C",
                        "d": "D"
                    },
                    {
                        "a": "E",
                        "b": "F",
                        "c": "G",
                        "d": "H"
                    },
                    {
                        "a": "I",
                        "b": "J",
                        "c": "K",
                        "d": "L"
                    }   
              ]
}
```

Second Object:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "field1": "property1" 
    "field2": [ 
                    {
                        "a": "A",
                        "b": "B",
                    },
                    {
                        "a": "E",
                        "b": "F",
                    },
                    {
                        "a": "I",
                        "b": "J"
                    }   
              ]
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow helps those who help themselves... what have you *tried*?

Comment: Also, your json is invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. Here is one.

Iterate through your `field2` array and use [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) to remove the desired object properties.

```js
let data = {
  "id": 1,
  "field1": "property1",
  "field2": [{
      "a": "A",
      "b": "B",
      "c": "C",
      "d": "D"
    },
    {
      "a": "E",
      "b": "F",
      "c": "G",
      "d": "H"
    },
    {
      "a": "I",
      "b": "J",
      "c": "K",
      "d": "L"
    }
  ]
}
data.field2.forEach(obj => {
  delete obj.c
  delete obj.d
})
console.log(data)
```